# Show 3 latest posts from featured category (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, posts

On a startpage I'm working on, I want to show only the 3 latest posts witch has the tag featured. Must be a really basic thing to do with "The Loop", but I can't find the answer anywhere, and it feels like I have really looked everywhere :(

Can someone help me?

Comment: do you want show latest 3 post base on featured category or featured tag or both bcoz you mention in title category and in content mention tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look to the WP reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
It will be like this:

```
$featured_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'tag' => 'featured',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
));
```

Comment: That looks like a solution, I tested it but it only iterates once. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682329/wp-query-headache

Comment: Hahaha... I had only one post tagged featured, your example worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
query_posts('tag=featured&posts_per_page=3&order=DESC'); // show latest 3 posts on featured tag

//query_posts('category_name=featured&tag=featured&posts_per_page=3&order=DESC'); // show latest 3 posts on featured tag and featured categorey

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
        <!-- do stuff ... -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use following query to get latest 3 post.

```
"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE featured=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3"
```

*id=pk